# Strangely, Drupal saved pages show URL with ellipsis

Tags: drupal-7

I created several pages and some of them have a truncated URL like:

```
localhost:8888/staff/developm...
```

while others are normal. Can't figure out what happened. I've never seen it before.

Comment: could you share your setting file or code

Comment: Which file would you like to see? Or what code?

Comment: It would be useful to see your HTML output. You can use your navigator's developer tools to see which file is including the ellipsis CSS instruction. A list of the active modules would also be helpful.